# Maximum Servlet Output on Glassfish Issue

Tags: java, xml, servlets, glassfish

I have a servlet which outputs XML. I've attempted in a number of ways of output, making sure I'm consistently flush the PrintWriter.

It works up to around 49500 characters. Over that kind of limit the output given is nothing.

Deploying the code on to Tomcat it works perfectly (without the limit problem).

Is there a setting somewhere on GlassFish? I altered the Xmx for the server-config from 512M to 1024M as a test, but this didn't appear to make any difference.

Any guidance gratefully received.

Cheers,
Greg

Comment: Are you getting an error in the server log?

Comment: @Preston Nothing at all unfortunately. Also checked the PrintWriter.hasError() method, and its returning false. Just had a minor breakthrough with removing the GZipper filter - testing further as we speak.

Comment: A bit of a wasted day hunting this down. Turned out there was a GZipper filter sitting inbetween the servlet and the caller.

Removing the GZipper filter makes the xml come out correctly. More investigations tomorrow I guess.

Comment: Glad you're on the track. Post the answer when you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Haven't had time to fully investigate but hoping I might get some time over the weekend to have a good play around.

We seemed to have an issue with the GZipper setting on Glassfish and the chunked data response. By removing those settings from the server, all appeared to work fine.

This forum discussion seems to be in keeping with what we saw. Need to note saw this Glassfish 3.1.1.

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/empty-response-gzip